# Get the artist and song title from Youtube video by API

Tags: youtube-api

I am wondering if it's possible to retrive the artist and song title from a YouTube video using the YouToube API. I think I can just parse the title, then search from API by artist (for example: `http://www.youtube.com/artist?a=cJmvMpoqHdQ`), but it's not an optimal solution.  Is there a more efficient/appropriate way of solving this problem?

Comment: Hi - did you ever figure out a nice way to do this?  I've got the same problem.  thanks

Comment: Unfortunately no, I dropped the idea completely @Max

Comment: Feel free to upvote [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/181347378) if you want to see this feature added.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its only response refers to an API endpoint that has been deprecated.

Answer (score -3):

You should be able to get most of details by passing Video id which is available in
the youtube url.
On making request to the below url u can get title , artist and many more..
Just enter the video id in the below url you will get a JSON response with all details..

(http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/**Db9FBvpx49M**?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=youtubeFeedCallback )

Comment: Unfortunately in this way i cannot get such meta as Artist and Song title.. As You see in this video: [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30w8DyEJ__0) there is highlighted artist (in the title and below video under view stats). And this is the meta i want to grab. Thank You anyway.

Comment: Hi you can get video title from the above url. As of now there is no direct way to get this meta .You have to do a youtube crawler to get the info you required. eg: http://www.tubekit.org/index.php , https://gitorious.org/youtube-related-videos-crawler

Comment: For the link you provide you can crawl the website for this element to fetch author <span class="metadata-info">
Artist: <span class="link-like">Arctic Monkeys</span>
    </span>  .

Comment: Thank you @Alvin. The biggest problem with this solution is that when i'll have hundreds or thousands of videos to crawl it will take more than minutes.. At least, you guys made me sure, that it's not possible to do it with YT API :)

Comment: To clarify, this answer will not work in the general case.  One (less simple) solution is to integrate with a third party API like MusicBrainz, though it's definitely not perfect.

Comment: v2 of the api has now been shut down